# Parse pin fetched object to local store

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm working with the Parse.com Android SDK and want my app to work offline as well as online for the most parts.
I have an object "Friends" including a ParseUser object in one column. In my app I want to get the ParseUser's username when having the Friends object (ParseObject). When my app is online, there are no problems. Initially i query for all Friends objects, pin all of them to make them available in my local datastore, save them in a List and later call `((ParseUser) friendList.get(i).get("user")).getUsername()` what actually works fine. But when the app is offline, an exception gets thrown in this line, because the 'inner' ParseUser object's data is not available without internet connection. It looks like the Friends objects get pinned, but the inner ParseUser objects don't get stored with all their data, but only with their ids in order to fetch them from the server. How can i store the entire Friends object recursively, affecting all it's inner objects, too?

```
// When online
public void loadFriends() {
        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PARSE_FRIENDS_CLASS);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(list);
                    friends.addAll(list);
                } else {
                    loadFriendsLocally();
                }
                timer.cancel();
            }
        });

// When offline
private void loadFriendsLocally() {
        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PARSE_FRIENDS_CLASS);
        query.fromLocalDatastore();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    friends.addAll(list);
                }
                else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And the line where the exception gets thrown (in an ArrayAdapter's getView() method):

```
usernameView.setText(((ParseUser) item.get(UserManager.FRIEND_COLUMN)).getUsername());
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ? I seem to be stuck with the same

Answer (score 0):

Pin the inner objects of the `Friend` object especially when you're using `ParseRelation`.